# Function to return true if a cell in a range is red

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to get my function "ScanColor" to return True when any cell in the range "lockdown" has the interior color red.

If a cell in the range "lockdown" does have a cell that is red i'd like to prompt a msg box.

Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)  
    If ScanColor(Range("lockdown")) = True Then
        MsgBox "You have an invalid cell!"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ScanColor(Cells As Range) As Boolean
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Cells
        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            ScanColor = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Could you explain the issue? Are you getting an compile or runtime error? If so, what are the error number(s) and description(s). If the code "runs" fine, but doesn't give the expected result, what result are you getting instead? Have you tried using breakpoints and/or walking through your code? Are you sure that the cells are the same shade of red you're searching for?

Comment: How is the color changed?  Is it through conditional formatting or manually.  If Manually you will not be able to capture the color change.  If it is through conditional formatting, does the manual change that triggers the conditiona formatting happen on that sheet, or is it a result of formula?  If a result of formula you will want to use Worksheet_calculate.  Also yo will want to use [Range.Displayformat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-displayformat-property-excel)

Comment: Mistella - No error, but when I change the sheet I do not get the popup. I believe thats because the function is returning false.

Comment: Scott - It is changed through conditional formatting. I have a custom formula to display it as red if the value doesn't match whats in the datavalidation list. The Manual change that triggers is a Paste Values that doesn't match what is in the dropdown.

Comment: `cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3`

Comment: Sometimes the `Interior.ColorIndex` is not what you think it should be.  To check your work, write a macro that returns the actual color index of your red, conditionally-formatted cell.  I bet you'll find out it's not "3," and you'll find out what your test condition actually should be.

Comment: Thank you Scott - I was missing the "displayformat".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change from conditional formatting must  be determined from the DisplayFormat property.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)  
    If ScanColor(Range("lockdown")) Then
        MsgBox "You have an invalid cell!"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ScanColor(Cells As Range) As Boolean
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Cells
        If cell.displayformat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            ScanColor = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

There is some question as to whether the Worksheet_Change will be triggered. You might want a Worksheet_Calculate instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help. When I changed to displayformat it returned "True".